# Column is invalid in select list

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am trying to add a `Nvarchar` column to my select list which I need in the result set. But when I execute I get this error:

> Column 'dbo.SourceEntity.SourceName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I don't need to aggregate this column or `group by` it. How do I get this column into my result set? Here is my code:

```
SELECT  distinct
la.Limit AS keyfield, 
convert(varchar(100), se.SourceName) AS SourceEntity,   
(la.Limit) AS Limit,
SUM(la.ARLimit) AS LAARLimit,
SUM(la.MTMLimit) AS LAMTMLimit,
SUM(la.Volume) AS LAMaxVolume,
SUM(la.MaxTenor) AS LAMaxTenor, 

SUM(le.ARLimit) AS LEARLimit, 
SUM(le.MTMLimit) AS LEMTMLimit, 
SUM(le.Volume) AS LEMAxVolume, 
SUM(le.MaxTenor) AS LEMaxTenor, SUM(la.ARLimit) + SUM(le.ARLimit) AS [ARLimit], 
SUM(la.MTMLimit) + SUM(le.MTMLimit) AS [MTMLimit], 
SUM(la.Volume) + SUM(le.Volume) AS [Volume], 
SUM(la.MaxTenor) + SUM(le.MaxTenor) AS [MaxTenor]
FROM            
dbo.LimitAllocation AS la 
INNER JOIN

dbo.LimitExtension AS le ON la.Limit = le.Limit AND la.Limit = le.Limit

inner join 

dbo.SourceEntity as se on la.SourceEntity = le.SourceEntity
GROUP BY la.Limit
```

Comment: Is SourceName a constant? If you use Group By, then everything you select has to be either the group by value, or an aggregate value. Also, look at the join with se. Are you mistyping something?

Comment: What do you mean by `I do not need to group by` this column? Are the grouping results incorrect if you group by it? Also, what version of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: What is the relationship of the data in this column to la.Limit i.e. is it unique for each change in la.Limit or are there more than one?

Comment: there are many SourceEntities in a Limit

Comment: @Minh Is this what you mean? should be this: inner join 

dbo.SourceEntity as se on la.SourceEntity = se.oid and le.SourceEntity = se.Oid

Comment: Yes, something like that

Comment: you should just add `SourceEntity` to your group by, or remove it from the Select.  if you have many `SourceEntities in a Limit ` then you will get a row for each `SourceEntities`  if you dont want a row for each `SourceEntities` either remove it from the select or use an aggregate like `MIN` or `MAX` to only get one

Comment: @JamieDD7 Ok. I was using MAX. But I thought MAX just gave me the highest INT in that column. Are you saying MAX will return the most amount rows in the table?

Comment: you thought right.. it will give you the highest value.  Your Joins look way off .  should probably be `FROM dbo.LimitAllocation AS la JOIN dbo.LimitExtension AS le ON la.Limit = le.Limit JOIN dbo.SourceEntity se ON le.SourceEntity = se.SourceEntity`

Comment: @JamieD77. Thanks. I forgot I can dd more than one column to a Group by clause. I got past the error. I think the results are correct. But I will try your Join suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Hint :    get your sums, joins and wheres working....then lastly, one field at a time, add your Group By fields...   it will be more clear then what the error messages are trying to tell you.   One none-summed field at a time, and be sure to list that field in both the SELECT phrase and in the GROUP BY phrase.

Comment: The joins between the tables may be disrupting your counts.  You may need to use a subselect to get the totals first, or use analytics ('over' syntax) to get sums first..

Answer (score 0):

Try with this you will get your extra column also in the result set.

```
select *,convert(varchar(100), SourceName) AS SourceEntity
from (
  SELECT distinct
    la.Limit AS keyfield, 
    (la.Limit) AS Limit,
    SUM(la.ARLimit) AS LAARLimit,
    SUM(la.MTMLimit) AS LAMTMLimit,
    SUM(la.Volume) AS LAMaxVolume,
    SUM(la.MaxTenor) AS LAMaxTenor, 
    SUM(le.ARLimit) AS LEARLimit, 
    SUM(le.MTMLimit) AS LEMTMLimit, 
    SUM(le.Volume) AS LEMAxVolume, 
    SUM(le.MaxTenor) AS LEMaxTenor,
    SUM(la.ARLimit) + SUM(le.ARLimit) AS [ARLimit], 
    SUM(la.MTMLimit) + SUM(le.MTMLimit) AS [MTMLimit], 
    SUM(la.Volume) + SUM(le.Volume) AS [Volume], 
    SUM(la.MaxTenor) + SUM(le.MaxTenor) AS [MaxTenor]
  FROM dbo.LimitAllocation AS la 
  INNER JOIN dbo.LimitExtension AS le ON la.Limit = le.Limit AND la.Limit = le.Limit
  inner join dbo.SourceEntity as se on la.SourceEntity = le.SourceEntity
  GROUP BY la.Limit
) as p;
```

Comment: Thanks Phani. I am attempting your code. But I am getting an error. SourceName cannot be bound on the first line: select *,convert(varchar(100), SourceName) AS SourceEntity. I have also tried se.OID and I get the same eror. It seems the se table is unreachable from this code. I like the idea of a sub query. Do you know how I could resolve this error?